# how do you create a subsection in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to create a R markdown like below. In a vector called app, I will have several application, will go though and create a pdf file

````
---
title: "Java Based Apps"
date: "January 13, 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: true
    highlight: zenburn
    fig_width: 7
    fig_height: 6
    fig_caption: true

tables: yes
keep_tex: true
fontsize: 12
---



```{r message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

app<-c("Sample APP")

for (i in app){

    cat(paste("## ", "- Correlation Analysis between performance KPI's"))
    cat("\n")
    m<-corrplot(M, method="number")

    cat(paste("## ", "- JVM %CPU Usage"))
    cat("\n")

    print(ggplot(data, aes(Date, JVM_CPU, group=JVM))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F)+theme_bw()+
    ggtitle(paste(i, " - JVM %CPU Usage/15 Minute Interval"))+facet_wrap(~JVM, scale="free"))

    cat(paste("## ", "- JVM Heap Usage"))
    cat("\n")

    print(ggplot(data, aes(Date, JVM_Mem, group=JVM))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F)+theme_bw()+
    ggtitle(paste(i, " - JVM Memory Usage/15 Minute Interval"))+facet_wrap(~JVM, scale="free")+ylab("Memory Usage/MG"))

 }
```
````

the output needs to be like this:

```
Sample App
   - Correlation Analysis between performance KPI's
   - JVM %CPU Usage
   - JVM Heap Usage
```

etc

I am seeing this:

```
Sample App
   - Correlation Analysis between performance KPI's
```

but others are not being created as subsections. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: that's bizarre.  If you remove the plots, the 3 sections work as intended, as soon as you add something in between, the sections stop working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you divide the problem its easier. I created some bogus data.

You can have a `main.Rmd` where you run the `for` loop such as:

---

````
title: "Java Based Apps"
date: "January 13, 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: true
    highlight: zenburn
    fig_width: 7
    fig_height: 6
    fig_caption: true
tables: yes
keep_tex: true
fontsize: 12
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F, message = F, warning = F)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(corrplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
# Create some sample data
set.seed(2887)
data <- tibble(
  app = sort(rep(c("sample app", "sample app 2"), 500))
  , Date = rep(seq(now() - as.difftime(7, unit="days"), now(), length.out = 500), 2)
  , JVM = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 1000, replace = T)
  , JVM_CPU = runif(1000, 0, 100)
  , JVM_Mem = runif(1000, 0, 100)
)
```

```{r}
app <- sort(unique(data$app))

out <- NULL
for (i in app){
  data.filtered <- dplyr::filter(data, app == i)
  out <- c(out, knit_child('app_template.Rmd', quiet = TRUE))
}
```

`r paste(out, collapse='\n')`
````

You will iterate over a template which here I have called `app_template.Rmd` and looks like this (notice that it has no `yaml`:

````
\pagebreak

# `r i`

## Correlation Analysis between performance KPI's

```{r, fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)
M <- cor(m)
corrplot(M, method="number")
```

## JVM %CPU Usage

```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=5}
ggplot(data.filtered, aes(Date, JVM_CPU, group=JVM)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) + 
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle(paste(i, " - JVM %CPU Usage/15 Minute Interval")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ JVM, scale = "free")
```

## JVM Heap Usage

```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=5}
ggplot(data.filtered, aes(Date, JVM_Mem, group = JVM)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) + 
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle(paste(i, " - JVM Memory Usage/15 Minute Interval")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ JVM, scale = "free") + 
  ylab("Memory Usage/MG")
```
````

If you `knit` the `main.Rmd` you should get a `.pdf` with your specifications.

Comment: how do you perform knit the .Rmd file to produce .pdf file from the command line?

Answer (score 9):

Add `cat("\n\n")` after each plot to add space.  That should help make the ## work to separate the subsections properly.

Comment: ok, the charts shows up but they show one after another. I want them to show in sections. For example, after heading JVM Cpu heading, there should be the jvm cpu chart, after JVM Heap Usage heading, the JVM Heap usage chart etc. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Would you post your amended code?  When I tested on my own three graphs using the iris data (you didn't provide a reproducible example), I had no problem getting one graph per subsection.

Comment: "charts shows up but they show one after another. " this may be due to the latex rendering floating figures, try reducing figure size and placing a `\pagebreak` after each plot to see if that helps.

Comment: For me all the figures appear in their appropriate sections.  If you really want to force the sections to be populated with the floats you could include a `\clearpage` command after each section which would force latex to put the figures in those sections.

Comment: @LloydChristmas, for example, I have this piece of code m<-corrplot(M, method="number")
   \clearpage, it looks like it does not like the backslash.

Comment: You need to use double backslash, `cat("\\clearpage")`  or `cat("\\newpage")`  since you are in a R code chunk.

Comment: @LloydChristmas, cat("\\clearpage") kinda works but I have figure on each page. I need headers and plot to be on the same page. cat("\n\n") does not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: You would only put ``clearpage`` at the end of each section (not after each plot).  If the section heading and the first plot are not on the same page it could be simply due to the size of the image relative to the page.  Also @PaulRougieux comment about latex rendering floating figures is also true.  Things start to break when you try to force it to do things.